# Which of the GPIO pins are suitable for controlling the WS2812 strips?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, ws2812

I'm running multiple (6), separate WS2812 strips off of one Raspberry Pi4.

They each need to be running independently - so the strip running on pin D18 will be getting different commands to the strip running on pin D21. I am using a logic-level converter and the strips are powered separately.

The issue I'm running into is that it seems like Raspberry Pi's can only run WS2812 or neopixels off of pins `D10`, `D12`, `D18` and `D21`.

Are there any workarounds that I might not be aware of?

### UPDATE

According to Adafruit's [guide on WS2812 with Raspberry Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-wiring) you can only

> Create one strip at a time.

They don't explain why this is the case.

After some testing, I am able to run two strips (one on pin `D21` and one on pin `D18`) separately.  We think that this may be due to the Pi only having two software PWM pins but we are not sure.

### UPDATE 2

Running two strips at the same time on pins D21 and D18 only works for a short length of time (10mins).  One of the strips stops responding entirely.

What we decided to do is use three Raspberry Pi Zero W's each running one LED strip communicating via MQTT with a Pi4 which is connected to our sensors and audio.

The problem remains, however:

Why can only pins `D10`, `D12`, `D18` and `D21` run WS2812 strips and why can only one strip be run at a time?

Comment: you only need one pin ... all the LEDs on a strip are independent already

Comment: Thanks for the response, but does that imply that I'd need to daisy chain all of the LEDs? They're spread out over a large area and we're trying to conserve cabling

Comment: @jsotola: Please consider making an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: yes, the strips would have to be daisychained

Comment: Ah, unfortunately, that would require too much cabling (running from the end of one strip back to the next).

Comment: @AndrewEarl If there are important physical constraints, rather than just electrical and software issues, you should explain those in your question. Don't add the details in comments; edit the question itself.

Comment: @AndrewEarl I took the liberty to clarify the title of your post ... hopefully it now reflects your question

Comment: if all the strips start in the same place and end in the same place (like stripes on the American flag) you don't need to run a cable back to the start. Instead, reverse (swap start and end) every other strip and handle the change in LED order in software.

Comment: ＠Andrew Earl，Why only 4 pins: D10, D12, D18 and D21? Have you tried all other GPIO pins?

Comment: WS2812 protocol is 1 wire async NRZ, 800kHz max, 5m max. If you want longer wiring, you need to DIY repeaters. Ref: 
https://i.imgur.com/fHON6Bv.jpg. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01I am using the neopixel library and it seems like D10, D12, D18 and D21 are the only pins that run WS2812s.  Furthermore, we are running a Pi DAC for audio which uses another 10 pins.

Comment: @tlfong0 regardless of the constraint of using the Pi DAC it still seems that Raspberry pi's are not able to run more than one strip at a time.  We have used other Pi's running WS2812 strips off of pins D18 and D21 - both will run for a short amount of time before one of the pins stops responding.

Comment: @SteveRobillard the layout and placement of the strips are very complicated (they are in a tree).  As such having them all connected/daisy chained together isn't a feasible solution.

Comment: @Andrew Earl, (1) I forgot why you need the Pi DAC. (2) WS2812 needs ridiculously stringent timing. So very soon it loses sync/step. (3) Perhaps you can use Pi Pico, where all problems disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of one the BCM GPIO `D18`, `D21`, `D10`, `D12` can independently control a `WS2812B` RGB LED strip.

### Notice

1. If there are more than `30 LEDs` in a strip, an `external power supply` needs to be added;
2. If you want to use BCM GPIO `D10` or `D12`, you must first enable `SPI` on the Raspberry Pi;

> By the way: Each `5050 RGB LED` will draw 20mA(min) to 60mA(max)

[image]

### refs

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin12_gpio18

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin40_gpio21

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNlaj1r7NKc